# how to find page templates in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to wordpress and I'm using a woocommerce theme and I'm struggling to work with the page templates.

As an example I have a page called 'Sample' and this says its page template is the 'Default Template'. If i modify the file page.php then it modifies the output of Sample as I would expect.

But there is a page called Shop which says it also has the page template 'Default' but if I modify page.php the output of Shop isnt altered at all. Is this something to do with woocommerce?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide to the woocommerce template structure
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

but read these first

The template structure for wordpress http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

and the codex entry on creating custom page templates http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates